# How do I upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.04.1

Tags: upgrade

I have heard(you tube)tha the wifi problems in Ubuntu 16.04 are fixed in 16.04.1.Therefore.how do I upgrade?Or is it easier to do a clean install?When I do lsb_release -a I get this-  No LSB modules are available.Distributor ID: Ubuntu  Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS   Release:16.04   Codename   xenial   I have disabled the internal combo wifi/bluetooth and am using a USB dongle.

Comment: Don't know what that means.Sorry.

Comment: open up a terminal, and give type the command: `lsb_release -a` then hit [ENTER] it will provide output. copy that output to your question.

Comment: I get this-  No LSB modules are available.Distributor ID: Ubuntu  Release 16.04  Codename xenial

Comment: Copy the output of `lsb_release -a` to your question instead of posting them as comment.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes from https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/07/28/ubuntu-version-16-04-point-1-is-out/.

> **If you are already running 16.04 LTS you will have been receiving updates incrementally and there is nothing more for you to do.** If you’re installing afresh then you should download the 16.04.1 ISO image from the Ubuntu website, the web team will be updating the default download links as soon as the images are published.

So yeah, if you happen to update on or after the date *28 July 2016*, then your system should have 16.04.1 automatically.

If you didn't receive `.1` point release, run following on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

To verify you are running 16.04.1, run `cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION=`:

```
Liso@thinkpad:~$ cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION=
VERSION="16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

Comment: Went ahead and did a clean install anyway,but thanks for the info.Seems to be working now.